# Entity Framework 5.0 Complex Types

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to use a complex type as a key on an entity, however I can't get it to work and not sure if this is just a limitation of the version I am using. I am sure that I have seen it done somewhere.

Can a complex type be used as an key in Entity Framework 5.0??

If so how can this be done??

```
    public class Identity : IIdentity
{
    public string Id { get; protected set; }

    public Identity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public Identity(string id)
    {

    }
}

    public class ReviewId : Identity
{
    public ReviewId(string id): base(id)
    {
    }

    public ReviewId()
    {
    }
}

    public class Review
{
    public ReviewId ReviewId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework complains about using ReviewId as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF does not support ComplexType keys.